# MPNowPlayingInfoCenter and MPRemoteCommandCenter works in simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I'm integrating MPNowPlayingInfoCenter into a music playing app. The integration of that and MPRemoteCommandCenter work great when I run it in the iOS simulator. When I run the same code on a device the music controls in Control Center do not change at all. It's as if the app isn't event registering with MPNow and MPRemote centers.

```
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *np = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];

np.nowPlayingInfo = @{MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:[tracks objectAtIndex:self.currentTrack],
                      MPMediaItemPropertyArtist:currentArtist,
                      MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle:currentAlbum,
                      MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType:@(MPMediaTypeMusic),                                 
                      MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration:@(self.audioHandler.audioDuration),        
                      MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime:@(self.audioHandler.position),
                      MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate:rate
};
```

I've got all this good stuff in my view controller life cycle methods:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    // Turn off remote control event delivery
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

    // Resign as first responder
    [self resignFirstResponder];

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

A couple notes:

1. I'm not using AVPlayer. I'm using CoreAudio/Audio units to play
   the audio. This part of the app is working fine.
2. I'm testing on iOS 7 and iOS 8 only.
3. I'm using the Amazing Audio Engine as a CoreAudio wrapper:  http://theamazingaudioengine.com

Answer (score 4):

Found it. When initializing the amazing audio engine (a great framework by the way) one needs to tell the framework that it doesn't want to share the audio output with other apps if one wants to use the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.  To do this I did:

```
self.audioController = [[AEAudioController alloc]
          initWithAudioDescription:[AEAudioController nonInterleaved16BitStereoAudioDescription]
                      inputEnabled:NO];
self.audioController.allowMixingWithOtherApps = NO;
```